# Why is MongoDB and MySQL slower than grep?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, optimization, grep, database

I'm doing some test on Wikipedia's pagecount data. This consists of around 7 million lines that look like this:

`es London 13 173367`

The 3rd column is the the count and I want to sum this across articles that have the same name (2nd column). So, on the command line:

`paste -sd + <(grep ' London ' pagecounts | cut -d ' ' -f 3) | bc`

Which works great and takes **0.53s**

I thought that using a DB to query the information would be faster so I loaded it all into a MongoDB database, then:

```
db["pagecounts"].aggregate({
    $match: { "article": "London" }
}, {
    $group: { _id: "London", "total": { $sum: "$count" } }
});
```

This works, but takes a horrifying **8.96s**

Confused and disappointed, I turned to MySQL:

`SELECT SUM(count) FROM pagecounts WHERE article='London';`

Which took **5.08s**

I don't know a great deal about the internals of databases, but I wouldn't have thought that command line tools like `grep` would be faster at this kind of thing. What's going on? And what can be improved?

**UPDATE**

As Cyrus and Michael suggested, creating and index made this WAY faster: ~**0.002s**.

Comment: Databases provide a lot of functionality that command line tools don't.  It is not surprising that a special purpose tool (grep) outperforms a database on a particular task.

Comment: Try to [add an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html) to column `article` in your mysql database to avoid a full table scan.

Comment: Same goes for MongoDB - you want to index on the city name to make this faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cyrus has suggested, you need an index.

```
ALTER TABLE pagecount ADD KEY (article);
```

Then try the query again.

You should, while benchmarking, use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid seeing query times that are deceptively faster than the server will consistently deliver.